# Why does my sql server database "full backup" not contain recent data?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I just migrated a SQL Server 2008 database while the sales staff went to lunch. I did a full backup and then copied the backup to the new server where I restored it to the new SQL Server installation.

The staff got back from lunch and told me that a few of the recent deals they put in right before lunch were no longer showing up in the system. Upon investigation it seems that the full backup was not including some of the very recent data that was added to the database before the backup was performed.

I suspect there is something I'm not accounting for that relates to the transaction log, but not being a MSSQL specialist, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd recommend reading this article to get a good handle on how SQL backups work. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Did you back up just the database, or with transaction logs as well? My guess is that you didn't backup transaction logs, which will contain recent transactions not yet flushed down to the mdb file.

Comment: They also could have added the data after the backup was done.

Comment: Nobody added any data after the backup was performed.

Comment: I did a "full backup" - I couldn't find any enabled option to include or exclude the transaction log, so I had to assume it was all-inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The data may have been entered in an open transaction. Since the backup has to adhere to the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) model, if a transaction was started before the backup started and was not committed by the time the backup has completed, the transaction will be rolled back upon restoring the database.

Comment: I went back about an hour later and tried to do another full backup of the original database, after confirming that the "missing" data was there, and the full backup still produced a version that was missing the last few rows of data that had been added into the database.

Answer (score -1):

This is why you never do these things during a work day! Next time do this over the weekend and close the database off to users by putting it in single user mode. They could have added the data after your backup or during it if you didn't lock them out first.

Comment: No, they didn't. There's just a few of them and I told them all to go lunch.

Comment: If it was added during the backup it would also be included in the full backup.  Database backups represent the whole database at the time the backup finished.